# SQL Column as a "View Column"

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have the following table `security` of securities:

```
  id   |   bbg_ticker     |  ticker  | currency | exchange |  type  
-------+------------------+----------+----------+----------+--------
  1762 | 653 HK Equity    | 653      |          | HK       | Equity 
  5734 | LO US Equity     | LO       |          | US       | Equity 
  6175 | H US Equity      | H        |          | US       | Equity 
  4563 | BDTY Index       | BDTY     |          |          | Index 
  6253 | MOA Comdty       | MOA      |          |          | Comdty 
  7414 | 1333 JP Equity   | 1333     |          | JP       | Equity 
  7538 | 2377 TT Equity   | 2377     |          | TT       | Equity
```

As you can guess, the Bloomberg ticker (column `bbg_ticker`) is actually the concatenation of:

- ticker + exchange + type if exchange is not null
- ticker + type else

This is obviously an irrelevant duplicating of data. For instance, one could one day change the `exchange` of a security without changing its `bbg_ticker`, which would lead to a failure in the data integrity.

As I am currently refactoring my database, I was wondering if I could do something like a "view" but with a column (not a whole table). This view would replace the `bbg_ticker`column (would be named the same), and would be defined for instance with (I know the following request is totally wrong):

```
CREATE COLUMN VIEW bbg_ticker
    ON security AS (
        ticker
        || (IF exchange IS NOT NULL THEN (' ' || exchange) ELSE '')
        || ' '
        || type
    )
;
```

It seems than VIEWS cannot be defined this way, but would you see another solution which would lead to the same result?
I know I could use check constraints and regex, which would solved the integrity question, but not the duplicating one. My question is more about having a better solution.

I am on PostgreSQL 9.5.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you create a view on top of your table, instead of column?

Comment: You mean creating a view with the same name as my table (security) ?? I didn't even know I could do this! :) If it's working, then I assume I would be perfect!!

Comment: Oh yes, it seems that it is impossible to create a view with the same name (logical...), but indeed create another view (for instance "securities") is a really good idea, thank you! Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a view from the whole table:

```
CREATE VIEW improved_security AS
    SELECT id, concat_ws(' ', ticker, exchange, type) AS  bbg_ticker,
           ticker, currency, exchange, type
    FROM security;
```

The `concat_ws()` function does all the nasty string concatenation for you, with the appropriate separator (a space in this case) and ignoring `NULL`s.

If you need to maintain the name `security` in order not to break any applications, then you should rename the table (which will require a table lock for a brief period of time) and then create the view with the name `security` and grant appropriate permissions to the view and revoke the same from the table. Wrap this all inside of a transaction so you will not get any errors on the client side, at best a brief delay in putting or pulling data.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, which agrees with the comment of @nomadus :). This solves my problem.

Comment: And above all thank you for the `concat_ws()` I totally didn't know!